# Word 2007 VBA: ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts

Tags: vba, ms-word

In [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/erikaehrli/data-driven-document-generation-with-word-2007-and-the-office-xml-file-formats-part-1) (and many others), there's an integer in the `CustomXMLParts` object collection `Load` method that I can't find an explanation for.  The Word 2007 VBA Reference doesn't seem to list the `Load` method either:

```
  ''# Load CustomerData.xml file
  ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add
  ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts(4).Load ("c:\CustomerData.xml")
```

What does the **4** represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are always **three** built-in CustomXMLParts in every .docx (created by Word 2007/2010 - not necessarily a .docx created by the Open XML SDK). Namely:

```
<cp:coreProperties xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties"><dc:creator></dc:creator><cp:keywords/><dc:description/><dc:subject/><dc:title/><cp:category/><cp:contentStatus/></cp:coreProperties>

<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties"><Company/><Manager/></Properties>

<CoverPageProperties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps"><PublishDate/><Abstract/><CompanyAddress/><CompanyPhone/><CompanyFax/><CompanyEmail/></CoverPageProperties>
```

So `4` here just means, after you've done `ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add` to add a fourth one "get the fourth one". If you had more, you would just use the next available index number. Instead of `4`, I'd probably just use this instead:

```
Dim ap As Document
Set ap = ActiveDocument
ap.CustomXMLParts.Add
ap.CustomXMLParts(ap.CustomXMLParts.Count).Load ("C:\CustomerData.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, one more quick question: if I want to have content controls in a .dotm template that are bound to an XML file, do I need to call the CustomXMLParts.Load (and the SetMapping method for each control) each time the document loads (i.e. Sub onload() ) or can I just save it after it's been executed?

Comment: You should just have to map it once, not each time. But if your XML data is changing between closing/opening documents, you'll want to sink the XMLNode events (bottom of this page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433905(office.12).aspx.

Comment: @Okatu, I have a similar question with a difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565185/iterating-xml-nodes-using-vba-word-2007-vba-retreiving-and-iterating-activedoc.  could you please help.